# Should a WSUS Server point WUServer to itself?

Tags: wsus, windows-update, windows-sbs-2011

On the Server running WSUS, should `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUStatusServer`
be configured to localhost/itself?

Does WSUS honor the Windows Update Service's settings to synchronise, or will WSUS use a separate connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSUS uses it's own settings.  I have used this exact setup on several networks.  WSUS pulls from an upstream server, approve the updates you want on your network, Windows Update Service queries WSUS and only downloads/installs those updates you approved.